# Using T-SQL, How do i select the max value of each inventory level for the month of the year given by the user?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am building a small program for myself to get to understand T-SQL better, and my Lecturer has provided some material for me to do this. I want to create a stored procedure using my view, vInventoryByType that shows me the max value of inventory level for each item of stock for a date (month/year) given by me in the EXEC line. The stored procedure needs to display the Product type name, Product subtype name and the max inventory level.

I Have tried the code below, however I am fairly new to T-SQL and do not have a lot of knowledge to mess around with. I do get an output, but not the one I need, Instead it supplies all records

```
USE MaxMinManufacturingDW
CREATE PROCEDURE spMaxInventoryByType @Year int = 0, @Month int = 0
AS
SELECT ProductTypeName, ProductSubtypeName, MAX(InventoryLevel)
FROM [vInventoryByType]
WHERE Year(DateOfInventory)= @Year AND Month(DateOfInventory) = @Month 
GROUP BY ProductTypeName, ProductSubtypeName, DateOfInventory

EXEC spMaxInventoryByType @Year = '2011', @Month = '01'
```

I expect the output to be the highest value of inventory per month for each subtype within the type, however I get the max value for every day within the month.

Comment: Asides: Since the parameters are of type `int`, why are you passing in string values, e.g. `'01'`? If you calculated the first and last date in the target month and used those values in the `where` clause the query could use an index on `DateOfInventory` to improve performance. See [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `DateOfInventory` from your `GROUP BY` clause

```
GROUP BY ProductTypeName, ProductSubtypeName  --, DateOfInventory
```